# Firebase user signOut doesn't work in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app and I'm handling the authentication with Firebase. The signIn create user functions work in the intended way, but for some reason, the signOut function doesn't work. When the button for the SignOut is clicked, the user should be signed out, but instead, he stays signed in

```
const signOutUser = () =>{
        console.log(authentication.currentUser.email)//before calling this is test@test.com
        signOut(authentication)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
        console.log("entered sign out functions")
        console.log(authentication.currentUser.email)//after above code runs this is till test@test.com
    }
```

Could somebody please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const signOutUser = () => {
    console.log(authentication.currentUser.email);
    signOut(authentication).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("entered sign out functions");
        console.log(authentication.currentUser.email);
    }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) })
}
```

or

```
const signOutUser = async() => {
    // add try catch if you want
    console.log(authentication.currentUser.email);
    const result = await signOut(authentication);
    console.log("entered sign out functions");
    console.log(authentication.currentUser.email);
}
```

You should await the signOut or write your code in then(). If this is still not working, you probably made a mistake with your `signOut(authentication)` function.

Comment: thanks that worked! Should I also be awaiting the signInWithEmailAndPassword function as well?

Comment: Basically, you wanna await everything that you need to await. Sounds dumb but for example: If you wanna have a function signIn() that is async and after that you want to want to either show a sigIn success or signIn failed message. You need to wait for the response and then react accordingly. In cases like that, you wanna await the function. If you have a function that just does stuff in the background and you don't need to wait for any response you don't need to await it. So yes, I would await signInWithEmailAndPassword and show a loading button as example

Comment: Just a heads up, in the second example result will await signout, but the 2 lines under it will not, you'd have to directly type await signOut(authentication) without assigning it to a variable to achieve what you want

Comment: No, that's wrong :) The 2 console logs will run after receiving the result :)